# From View post back Id, to controller function?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Using MVC, if the user clicks on the trash icon, it will `POST` the `mobileDevice.Id` from the view and call the `ConfirmDeactivate` action of the `MobileDeviceController`

```
//VIEW
     <a onclick="Deactivate(@mobileDevice.Id);" class="show-pointer"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Click here</a>

       <script>
      function Deactivate(mobileDeviceId) {
                alert(mobileDeviceId);

                 $.ajax({
                    url: 'MobileDevice/ConfirmDeactivate',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json;',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ targetid: mobileDeviceId })});

            }
             </script>

//controller
     [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ConfirmDeactivate(int targetid)
            {
    //update target
    }
```

am I missing a ajax ref or something?

Or does anyone have any other ideas? on this.

**UPDATE**
following an answer I have tried:

```
 //VIEW
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="post-btn" data-device-id="@mobileDevice.Id" class="show-pointer"><i class="icon-trash">/i>Click here</a>

      <script>
         $('#post-btn').on('click', function() {
          alert(targetid);
         $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ConfirmDeactivate", "MobileDevice")''~/MobileDevice/ConfirmDeactivate', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: { targetid: $(this).data('device-id') }
         });
         })
  </script>

//controller
     [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ConfirmDeactivate(int targetid)
            {
    //update target
    }
```

but this does not work. Tried to add an alert but this doesnt show

```
$('#post-btn').on('click', function() {
          alert(targetid);
```

Please advise

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Yes JQuery is defined, nothing happens when i press the 'bin'

Comment: Use your browser's debug tools and check your network traffic. Verify that it is sending the request, and that it's going to where you think it is. You should be able to use that to track down what's going wrong. If It's actually getting to the Controller Method, then you should be able to debug in there further.

Comment: My guess is that you should be using '~/MobileDevice/ConfirmDeactivate'.

Comment: Do as Maess instructed and put that in a $(document).ready() function and see if your alert fires.

Comment: delete '~/MobileDevice/ConfirmDeactivate' from your url

Comment: and see the last 2 comments to my answer

Comment: See the following http://jsfiddle.net/c2Xc4/  You can see that the alert is working, therefore the issue is with your ajax call, are you sure you are using the right url?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your code like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="post-btn" data-device-id="@mobileDevice.Id" class="show-pointer"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Click here</a>

$('#post-btn').on('click', function() {
             $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ConfirmDeactivate", "MobileDevice")', //I believe you should use this instead of 'MobileDevice/ConfirmDeactivate'
                type: 'POST',
                data: { targetid: $(this).data('device-id') }
             });
})
```

It should work if you defined jQuery, of course.

Comment: If you this to work, you need some event to actually call the code that adds the event handler, like the document ready event.

Comment: ive used this and nothing happens when i click the 'bin' icon? and yes JQuery is defined

Comment: @John, sorry, HREF was missing. See edited answer please

Comment: actually he's right, it should be in something like document.ready(), otherwise you run the risk of your objects not existing when you try to bind. It will 'probably' work, but the correct thing to do, is what Maess indicated. See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Mike C., I'm sorry but if you look more carefully to this api, you will see an example, where .on() used without any document.ready()

Comment: see "Example: Attach and trigger custom (non-browser) events." block script please

Comment: "To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page."

Comment: Sorry guys but this still isnt working...have you any ideas please?

Comment: Ive added an alert: $('#post-btn').on('click', function() {
              alert(targetid); but this isnt showing, so it isnt getting this far?

Comment: If this is the solution you're going with, please repost an update to your question with what you're currently using.

Comment: @John you will get an error with alert(targetid);, couse you have not defined variable "targetid"

Comment: try alert($(this).data('device-id'));